# Read lines defined by a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read specific lines from a file, and these lines are defined by another variable.

For example.
TR=[1,2,3]
ROI=file with many lines

I am trying find or make a code that will read lines from the ROI file, based on the numbers in the first line of the TR variable  (i.e., 1, 2, 3).

I've searched the database and have not been able to figure this out.

What I have so far, albeit very short... is:

```
TR=open('tr.txt')
TR=TRopen.readlines()
ROI=open('ROI.txt')
ROI=ROIopen.readlines()

TRline1 = TR[0]
TRline1 = [int(i) for i in TRline1.split()]
```

I've managed to split my list into integers, which would presumably be needed to call these numbers when reading from my ROI file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how about `print([x for i, x in enumerate(ROI) if i in TRline1])`?

Comment: That does exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then please accept the answer so that the question can be *closed*. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the line numbers you need (`TRline1`) and have already read the text into memory (`ROI`) you can simply do:

```
print([x for i, x in enumerate(ROI) if i in TRline1])
```